# Does `dd` work on physical level or on filesystem level?

Tags: linux, backup, filesystems, storage, dd

When you delete a file from a device, let's say an USB stick, then (without doing any further stuff) only the entry in the filesystem is deleted, the raw bytes of this file are still on the device (that's why file recovery tools work by scanning the physical sectors on the drive one by one).

Now, if I do

```
dd if=/path/to/usbdrive of=/backup/usbdrive.img
```

the content of USB drive will be copied to the specified file.

**When arriving at the location where the deleted file was, will `dd` copy zeros or will it copy the file content that physically is still there?**

Comment: I used it to copy a vmware hypervisor drive + client OS's to a bigger hard drive and everything worked when booting from the new drive, so I believe it reads 1 block and then writes that block to the destination verbatim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dd` merely copies an input stream of bytes to an output stream of bytes. Both input and output must be an actual file. It won't operate on a directory. So in your example above, if `/path/to/usbdrive` is a device node (i.e. `/dev/usb` or whatever) then it does a block-level copy since `/dev/usb` is a block device. It will copy the file content that was still there in that case. But you wouldn't be able to point the input stream to the file you just deleted because you wouldn't have the handle to it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It will copy the contents of the deleted file (assuming it was not overwritten by anyone). However at the destination you will not be able to access these contents as you are accessing it through the file system and your file system is unaware of file existing this space (since it was deleted).

So in terms of forensics, dd will copy all the garbage with bits and pieces of data that were on the source device.

Also you have to understand that there is always a fragmentation issue and your file could have been not in the contiguous disk space. This creates more complications.

I hope that explains it for you. At least if this is a theoretical question.

On the other hand, if this is a practical question, then I think if you would provide a better explanation of what are you tying to achieve, you would get more detailed answers.